# Visual studio cant load a buch of dlls

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2015, bgi

visual Studios is really messing my day uo today. I was just getting done with the base of my mario level editor ( made using winbgim graphics.h . Yes im using it with visual studio and it works a treat ) when i decidet to add a new basic block ( i only had questionmark blocks at a time ). The process was fairly easy just changed a few things and imported the new bitmap. I compiled the program and immediately i noticed that the program was running like there was a 2 secound delay somewhere. It took about 1,5 secounds to load the backround colour.
When i came out of visual studious these errors were in the debug window:

```
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Moustachespy\Source\Repos\CreateRemake\bgi\Release\bgi.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comdlg32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SHCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.10586.0_none_811bc0006c44242b\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\windows.storage.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\FirewallAPI.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\netapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\davhlpr.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\fwbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\coml2.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'bgi.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\asycfilt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0x4360 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2858 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x40f4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1e08 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[152] bgi.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I really dont know what happend there:
Heres the new code:

```
#include "graphics.h"
//#include <Windows.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>

void drawGridOnX(int xtotal, int ytotal);
int levelcode[400][45][1];
void decodelevelAndDraw(int minx,int maxx);
void saveCurrentLevel();

void main() {
    initwindow(1600, 900,"Testscreen",0,0,true,true);
    int x=0,y=0,xmin=0,xmax=23,cellx,celly,cellSize=70, xtotal = 0, ytotal = 0,counter=0,blockchosen=1;
    // gridposx = 0, gridposy = 0, diffx = 0, diffy = 0, distanceFromMouse = 40, titlenumberx = 0, titlenumbery = 0,

    while (1) {
        setbkcolor(9);
        cleardevice();
        ytotal = 0;
        /*diffx = mousex() - gridposx;
        while (gridposx < mousex()&&diffx>=70) {
            gridposx += 70;

        }
        while (gridposx > mousex()&&diffx<=-70 + distanceFromMouse) {
            gridposx =gridposx-70;

        }
        diffy = mousey() - gridposy;
        while (gridposy < mousey() && diffy >= 70) {
            gridposy += 70;

        }
        while (gridposy > mousey() && diffy <= -70+distanceFromMouse) {
            gridposy = gridposy - 70;

        }
        */
        cellx = std::floor(mousex() / cellSize);
        celly = std::floor(mousey() / cellSize);
        blockchosen = 0;
        while (ytotal < 900) {
            drawGridOnX(xtotal, ytotal);
            ytotal += 70;
        }

        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN)){
            //saveCurrentLevel();

        }
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT)) {
            blockchosen = 2;


        }else if (ismouseclick(WM_LBUTTONDOWN)) {
                if (ismouseclick(WM_LBUTTONUP)) {

                    getmouseclick(WM_LBUTTONUP, x, y);
                    getmouseclick(WM_LBUTTONDOWN, x, y);
                }
                //cellx = gridposx / 70;
                //celly = gridposy / 70;
                cellx += xmin;

                levelcode[cellx][celly][0]=blockchosen;
                //printf("CLICK");
            }else if (ismouseclick(WM_RBUTTONDOWN)) {
                    if (ismouseclick(WM_RBUTTONUP)) {

                        getmouseclick(WM_RBUTTONUP, x, y);
                        getmouseclick(WM_RBUTTONDOWN, x, y);
                    }
                    //cellx = gridposx / 70;
                    //celly = gridposy / 70;
                    cellx += xmin;
                    levelcode[cellx][celly][0] = 0;
                    //printf("CLICK");
                }else if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x27)) {
                        //printf("RIGHT\n\n\n\n");
                        Sleep(100);
                        xmin++;
                        xmax++;
                    }else if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x25)&&xmin!=0) {
                        //printf("RIGHT\n\n\n\n");
                        Sleep(100);
                        xmin--;
                        xmax--;
                }
        decodelevelAndDraw(xmin,xmax);
        readimagefile("question_blueprint.jpg", cellx*70,celly*70, 70+cellx*70, 70+celly*70);
        //settextstyle(SANS_SERIF_FONT,1);
        settextstyle(SANS_SERIF_FONT, HORIZ_DIR, 1);
        outtextxy(0, 0, "Press Enter to save");
        //printf("gridposx:%d\tgridposy:%d\ttitlenumberx:%d\ttitlenumbery%d",gridposx,gridposy,gridposx/70,gridposy/70);
        swapbuffers();

    }
}


void drawGridOnX(int xtotal, int ytotal) {
    while (xtotal < 1600) {
        rectangle(xtotal, ytotal, 70 + xtotal, 70+ytotal);
        xtotal += 70;

    }


}


void decodelevelAndDraw(int minx,int maxx) {
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    while (y != 13) {
        while (x != maxx) {
            if (levelcode[x][y][0] == 1) {
                //x -= minx;
                readimagefile("question.jpg", x*70-minx*70, y*70, 70 + x*70-minx*70, 70 + y*70);
                //printf("Block added at %d;%d", x * 70, y * 70);
            }else readimagefile("grass.bmp", x * 70 - minx * 70, y * 70, 70 + x * 70 - minx * 70, 70 + y * 70);
            x++;
        }
        x = 0;
        y++;
    }
}

/*
void saveCurrentLevel() {
    int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
    ofstream map;
    map.open("map.txt");
    while (y < 13) {


        while (x < 400) {
            map << levelcode[x][y][z];
        }
        x = 0;
        y++;
        map << "\n";
    }
    map.close();



}
*/
```

The old (and working ) code:
    #include "graphics.h"
    //#include 
    #include 
    #include

```
void drawGridOnX(int xtotal, int ytotal);
int levelcode[400][45][1];
void decodelevelAndDraw(int minx,int maxx);
void saveCurrentLevel();

void main() {
    initwindow(1600, 900,"Testscreen",0,0,true,true);
    int x=0,y=0,xmin=0,xmax=23,cellx,celly,cellSize=70, xtotal = 0, ytotal = 0,counter=0;
    // gridposx = 0, gridposy = 0, diffx = 0, diffy = 0, distanceFromMouse = 40, titlenumberx = 0, titlenumbery = 0,

    while (1) {
        setbkcolor(9);
        cleardevice();
        ytotal = 0;
        /*diffx = mousex() - gridposx;
        while (gridposx < mousex()&&diffx>=70) {
            gridposx += 70;

        }
        while (gridposx > mousex()&&diffx<=-70 + distanceFromMouse) {
            gridposx =gridposx-70;

        }
        diffy = mousey() - gridposy;
        while (gridposy < mousey() && diffy >= 70) {
            gridposy += 70;

        }
        while (gridposy > mousey() && diffy <= -70+distanceFromMouse) {
            gridposy = gridposy - 70;

        }
        */
        cellx = std::floor(mousex() / cellSize);
        celly = std::floor(mousey() / cellSize);
        while (ytotal < 900) {
            drawGridOnX(xtotal, ytotal);
            ytotal += 70;
        }

        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN)){
            //saveCurrentLevel();

        }else if (ismouseclick(WM_LBUTTONDOWN)) {
                if (ismouseclick(WM_LBUTTONUP)) {

                    getmouseclick(WM_LBUTTONUP, x, y);
                    getmouseclick(WM_LBUTTONDOWN, x, y);
                }
                //cellx = gridposx / 70;
                //celly = gridposy / 70;
                cellx += xmin;
                levelcode[cellx][celly][0]=1;
                //printf("CLICK");
            }else if (ismouseclick(WM_RBUTTONDOWN)) {
                    if (ismouseclick(WM_RBUTTONUP)) {

                        getmouseclick(WM_RBUTTONUP, x, y);
                        getmouseclick(WM_RBUTTONDOWN, x, y);
                    }
                    //cellx = gridposx / 70;
                    //celly = gridposy / 70;
                    cellx += xmin;
                    levelcode[cellx][celly][0] = 0;
                    //printf("CLICK");
                }else if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x27)) {
                        //printf("RIGHT\n\n\n\n");
                        Sleep(100);
                        xmin++;
                        xmax++;
                    }else if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x25)&&xmin!=0) {
                        //printf("RIGHT\n\n\n\n");
                        Sleep(100);
                        xmin--;
                        xmax--;
                }
        decodelevelAndDraw(xmin,xmax);
        readimagefile("question_blueprint.jpg", cellx*70,celly*70, 70+cellx*70, 70+celly*70);
        //settextstyle(SANS_SERIF_FONT,1);
        settextstyle(SANS_SERIF_FONT, HORIZ_DIR, 1);
        outtextxy(0, 0, "Press Enter to save");
        //printf("gridposx:%d\tgridposy:%d\ttitlenumberx:%d\ttitlenumbery%d",gridposx,gridposy,gridposx/70,gridposy/70);
        swapbuffers();

    }
}


void drawGridOnX(int xtotal, int ytotal) {
    while (xtotal < 1600) {
        rectangle(xtotal, ytotal, 70 + xtotal, 70+ytotal);
        xtotal += 70;

    }


}


void decodelevelAndDraw(int minx,int maxx) {
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    while (y != 13) {
        while (x != maxx) {
            if (levelcode[x][y][0] == 1) {
                //x -= minx;
                readimagefile("question.jpg", x*70-minx*70, y*70, 70 + x*70-minx*70, 70 + y*70);
                //printf("Block added at %d;%d", x * 70, y * 70);
            }
            x++;
        }
        x = 0;
        y++;
    }
}

/*
void saveCurrentLevel() {
    int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
    ofstream map;
    map.open("map.txt");
    while (y < 13) {


        while (x < 400) {
            map << levelcode[x][y][z];
        }
        x = 0;
        y++;
        map << "\n";
    }
    map.close();



}
*/
```

Im using the graphics.h files from this site: http://winbgim.codecutter.org/
Yes i absolutely HAVE to use graphics.h . Ask my teacher.
And yes i have to have that array as a global variable. Alot of people dont like that and im one of them but its just alot easier to work with. Its not like 1 array in global is gonna hurt anyone right?

Heres a zip of my ENTIRE project folder in case you need anything: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kym5r1sggmym78f/bgi.rar?dl=0

i know there are alot of comments in my program . They dont have anything to do with it. Those are just older methods i used that are now replaced by new ones. I left them there as a backup plan.

Im using : Win 10
VS2015 Community

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: The PDB files are required by the debugger. Did you switch between Release and Debug modes ? Also try a rebuild, just to see.

Comment: The pdb files should only be needed if you want to step inside and debug microsoft dlls. If you don't ignore the warnings. This has nothing to do with any problem you have executing your application. Also all of the DLLs were actually successfully loaded.

Comment: jeah but then why did the performance drop from simply adding one variable?

Answer (score 1):

Look at your `decodelevelAndDraw()` function.

The "old" one only drew "question.jpg" image if there was a `1` in the `levelcode` map for that cell.

The "new" one draws "grass.bmp" in **every** other cell. That has to take some time...

P.S. I don't know what your `readimagefile()` function does; I hope that it doesn't actually load the same JPEG image every time you need to draw it. Can it be pre-loaded just once?